# How do I add a default application icon to its desktop link in Plasma?

Tags: plasma5

After installing CentOS7 and creating a folder view in Plasma to store my future application shortcuts, I use "Link to Application..." to create shortcut to Google Chrome (via Application tab >  Command: /usr/bin/google-chrome). The shortcut launch Chrome when I open it no problem, but it has a question mark icon instead of the default Chrome one.

How do I use Chrome's icon as the shortcut icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the [Folder View Widget](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Folder_Views), the easiest way to have full-featured application links in a Folder View is to copy-paste existing applications' `.desktop` files into it. By default they are installed in `/usr/share/applications`.

As the name implies, a Folder View is a way to show the content of a directory on the Desktop or in a Panel. By right-clicking on a Folder View you can "Configure Folder View" to, among other things, choose the directory whose content it is showing or "Open with Dophin" to have that directory opened in the default file manager.

You will then see that each icon shown in the Folder View corresponds to a `.desktop` file (i.e. a [Desktop Entry](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/)). As far as I can tell, Plasma doesn't offer a GUI tool to fully customize a desktop entry—this is why copy-pasting an existing one is more convenient than creating a new one (as you did with "Create New" → "Link to Application"). You can, however, edit a desktop entry using a text editor. The displayed icon can be set by adding/editing the `Icon` key and making it point to an absolute path (e.g. `Icon=/path/to/myicon.png`) or to a name (e.g. `Icon=firefox`), which will be resolved using the algorithm explained in freedesktop.org's [Icon Themes specification](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/icon-theme-spec/).